# Slow apigee query when using geolocation with wildcard search

Tags: apigee, apigee-baas

We have a requirement to allow users to search for a business name and have the results sorted by proximity. A rather basic function. We are trying the following query but it takes up to a minute to come back with a response. If we exclude the geolocation constraint the response is instantaneous. Can someone let us know how we can optimize the query and/or entity collection.

```
https://api.usergrid.com/org/app/businesses/?ql=select * where business_name contains 'subway*' OR business_name='subway* AND location within 10000 of 49.3129366, -123.0795565&limit=10
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have made recent updates to the platform and queries are now significantly faster.  Basically instead of processing data from shards serially it is now done in parallel.

Unfortunately, with the previous (1.0) version each predicate would make the query much slower.  We have resolved that with the recent updates to 1.0 as well as in our 2.1 release.